# Navigation Scroll Highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code on a one-page scroll site that worked, but I've added the entire url into the href such as "href="index.php#home" instead of just using the hash. Now my active state isn't working. How can I amend this code for that to work?

```
                //Navigation Scroll / Highlight
            var aChildren = $(".nav li.link").children();
            var aArray = [];
            for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
                var aChild = aChildren[i];
                var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
                aArray.push(ahref);
            }

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop() + 140; // get the offset of the window from the top of page
                var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
                var docHeight = $(document).height();

                for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
                    var theID = aArray[i];
                    var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
                    var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
                    if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                        $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
                    } else {
                        $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                    }
                }

                if((windowPos + windowHeight) >= (docHeight - 140)) {
                    if (!$(".nav li.link:nth-last-child(2) a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
                        var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
                        $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                        $(".nav li.link:nth-last-child(2) a").addClass("nav-active");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/** 
 * This part does the "fixed navigation after scroll" functionality
 * We use the jQuery function scroll() to recalculate our variables as the 
 * page is scrolled/
 */
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() + 12; // the "12" should equal the margin-top value for nav.stick
    var div_top = $('#nav-anchor').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('nav').addClass('stick');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('stick');
        }
});

/**
 * This part causes smooth scrolling using scrollto.js
 * We target all a tags inside the nav, and apply the scrollto.js to it.
 */
$("nav a").click(function(evn){
    evn.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash); 
});

/**
 * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
 * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and 
 * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
 */
var aChildren = $("nav li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
    var aChild = aChildren[i];
    var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
    aArray.push(ahref);
} // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
        var theID = aArray[i];
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
        var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
        if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
        } else {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
        }
    }

    if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
        if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
            var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
            $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
            $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: It would be better to break the comments out of the code areas. It will provide better readability. You don't have to keep all the code together in one big section, you can break it into parts.